# I want to improve performance of my api endpoint(DJANGO)

Tags: django, performance, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest to request data of customers from an endpoint
suppose the endpoint is '/customers/list'

and my Query set is to get all customers

```
queryset = Customers.objects.all()
```

I am expecting to get so many customers which will affect the performance of the application that will consume this endpoint.
I am not willing to return the result set paginated so how can i improve the response time in case of too many records are processed.

Comment: Share your serializer and model. Other than reducing the number of DB queries if you access related models there is not much you can do

Comment: Thanks for your interest, the model already does not have relations.